# Empty response on HTTP request with netcat

Tags: netcat

Testing a simple HTTP request using `nc`:

```
$ printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: mozilla.org\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n' | nc mozilla.org 80
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 23:07:31 GMT
Location: https://www.mozilla.org/
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
```

But most hosts result in no output. Using the `-v` option result is positive:

```
Connection to stackoverflow.com.com 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
Connection to reddit.com 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

Using the `-D` option one line is given:

```
nc: Permission denied
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want `-q 1` (or 2 or 3 or something) as otherwise `nc` will exit before the remote server has issued its response.

`-D` probably requires `root`.

Comment: That catches me out every time with `nc`.

Answer (score 0):

You also might be missing some headers.

For example, `httpbin.org/get` would require `Accept:`  header, and other websites may require other headers to be present to trigger a response.